# How do I mock the tedis module with jest using typescript?

Tags: typescript, redis, jestjs, mocking

I'm using the tedis module ([link here](https://tedis.silkjs.org/)) to access a redis server and can make the connection fine, however when I try to mock the module, the test still runs the actual functions (lrange and lpop) as opposed to what I tried to return when mocking it.

This is how I am establishing the client connection in my code

```
import { Tedis } from "tedis";
const Client = new Tedis(
{
    host:"96.37.189.9",
    password:"Charter!234HDTI@utomation",
    port:6379
});
```

And this is how I'm trying to mock tedis to no avail

```
import { Tedis } from 'tedis';
jest.mock('tedis');
Tedis.lrange = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve(["please work"])
) as jest.Mock;
```

As I poked around I figured out that the real tedis.lrange was being called as opposed to the mock function, and was thus failing the test.

I tried then switching to the normal redis module but the password has an '@', which seems to break the url format used to create a client connection with redis as opposed to tedis.

I'm not really sure what to do because I'm going to need to write a lot of unit tests and don't want to put unnecessary strain on the redis server.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by replacing the `Tedis.lrange =...` section with the following line: `(Tedis.prototype.lrange as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(["please work"]));`